# Proving a line integral equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, vector-fields

Ive got an interesting question:

Without computing any integral, show that: $\int_{\vec{b}(t)}(x^{10}$**i**$+y^{10}$**j**$)· d\vec{b} = 0$

where $\vec{b}(t)=\sqrt{3}t^2$**i**$+(t^3-t)$**j** when $− 1 ≤ t ≤ 1$

This line integral question has stumped me. How am I meant to prove it without computing any integrals? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem).

Comment: You might want to exploit the fact that $\sqrt 3 t^2$ is even in $t$ while $(t^3-t)$ is odd .